# Android - Add a custom View to a ListView (to gain dim effect in a side menu)

Tags: android, listview, slidingdrawer, drawerlayout

I created an `Activity` and added a side menu using a `DrawerLayout`. Inside this `DrawerLayout` I added a `ListView` which houses the content. So far all good. I want to add a dim effect to the drawer by adding a custom view with a dim background, but it doesnt seem to work.

Here is the XML layout of the activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The first child in the layout is for the main Activity UI-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#ffffffff">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="SOME CONTENT"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
    <!-- this is the custom view that i want to add in order to dim the side menu -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#73000000"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_background"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Right now, it only dims the content of the activity, not the drawer itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `DrawerLayout` takes its last view as a drawer. So your last view is the `ListView` and the dim view is left to the content. If you want to make both the `ListView` and the dim `View` part of the drawer, you have to wrap them in a `ViewGroup`. Try creating a `RelativeLayout` that contains the two views. Something like this

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/drawerContainer"
  android:layout_width="270dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="left|start">
  <View
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#73000000"
     android:id="@+id/view1"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
  <ListView
     android:id="@+id/navList"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/splash_background"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```